# Regular expression for the "opposite" result

Tags: regex, r, gsub

Take the following character vector `x`

```
x <- c("1     Date in the form", "2     Number of game", 
       "3     Day of week", "4-5     Visiting team and league")
```

My desired result is the following vector, with the first capitalized word from each string and, if the string contains a `-`, also the last word.

```
[1] "Date"     "Number"   "Day"      "Visiting" "league"
```

So instead of doing

```
unlist(sapply(strsplit(x, "[[:blank:]]+|, "), function(y){
   if(grepl("[-]", y[1])) c(y[2], tail(y,1)) else y[2] 
}))
```

to get the result, I figured I could try to shorten it to a regular expression. The result is almost the "opposite" of this regular expression in `sub`.  I've tried it every which way to get the opposite, with different varieties of `[^A-Za-z]+` among others, and haven't been successful.

```
> sub("[A-Z][a-z]+", "", x)
[1] "1      in the form"       "2      of game"           
[3] "3      of week"           "4-5      team and league"
```

So I guess this is a two part question.

1. with `sub()` or `gsub()`, how can I return the opposite of `"[A-Z][a-z]+"`?
2. How can I write the regular expression to read like *"Match the first capitalized word and, if the string contains a `-`, also match the last word."*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

1. To extract the first capitalized word with `sub`, you can use

   ```
   sub(".*\\b([A-Z].*?)\\b.*", "\\1", x)
   #[1] "Date"     "Number"   "Day"      "Visiting"
   ```

   where `\\b` represents a word boundary.
2. You can also extract all word with one `sub` command, but note that you have to apply an extra step because the length of the vector returned by `sub` is identical to the length of the input vector `x`.

   The following regular expression makes use of a lookahead (`(?=.*-)`) to test if there's a `-` in the string. If it is the case, two words are extracted. If it's not present, the regular expression after the logical *or* (`|`) is applied and returns the first capitalized word only.

   ```
   res <- sub("(?:(?=.*-).*\\b([A-Z].*?\\b ).*\\b(.+)$)|(?:.*\\b([A-Z].*?)\\b.*)", 
              "\\1\\2\\3", x, perl = TRUE)
   # [1] "Date"            "Number"          "Day"             "Visiting league"
   ```

   One additional step is necessary in order to separate multiple words in the same string:

   ```
   unlist(strsplit(res, " ", fixed = TRUE))
   # [1] "Date"     "Number"   "Day"      "Visiting" "league"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using three regular expressions.

```
cap_words <- regmatches(x, regexpr("[A-Z][a-z]+", x))   # capitalised word
last_words <- sub(".*\\s", "", x[grep("-", x)]) # get last word in strings with a dash
c(cap_words, last_words)
# [1] "Date"     "Number"   "Day"      "Visiting" "league"
```