# Turn a character vector into a function call

Tags: r

How can I take this

```
d <- "3:10"
```

and magically turn it into this

```
[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

I've seen this done before, and searched SO extensively, but was unable to recall anything.

Here's what I've tried.

```
> eval(d)
# [1] "3:10"
> eval(noquote(d))
# [1] 3:10
> noquote(eval(d))
# [1] 3:10
> evalq(d)
# [1] "3:10"
> substitute(d)
# d
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the dreaded `eval(parse(...))` construct.

Try:

```
d <- "3:10"
eval(parse(text = d))
# [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

An interesting approach to this could be:

```
Reduce(":", as.numeric(strsplit(d, ":", TRUE)[[1]]))
# [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

And, whaddyaknow! I wouldnathunkit, but it's faster than `eval(parse(...))` (but your approach in the comment is faster yet).

```
fun1 <- function() Reduce(":", as.numeric(strsplit(d, ":", TRUE)[[1]]))
fun2 <- function() eval(parse(text = d))
fun3 <- function() {
  s <- as.numeric(strsplit(d, ":", fixed = TRUE)[[1]])
  s[1]:s[2]
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1(), fun2(), fun3())
# Unit: microseconds
#    expr     min       lq   median       uq     max neval
#  fun1()  24.375  26.0865  32.2865  55.8070 113.751   100
#  fun2() 108.192 112.4680 121.4490 204.8375 453.720   100
#  fun3()   8.553  10.6920  12.8300  20.9550  40.198   100
```

Comment: Aha!  Curious, why is it "dreaded"?  Many people on SO say that, about `eval` especially. Is it better to go with `s <- as.numeric(strsplit(d, ":")[[1]]); s[1]:s[2]` ?

Comment: @RichardScriven, `fortune(106)`? I'll dig up a couple of links. I've never had any problems with it myself though.

Comment: @RichardScriven, actually, [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+eval+parse) brings up the most relevant reasons for the `eval(parse(...))` construct. Regarding your subquestion, how did the data get in this form?

Comment: I'm parsing the text from [this link](http://www.retrosheet.org/gamelogs/glfields.txt) to create the header vector for the data it goes with. So I wanted to create these sequences to go along with the result from [my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670038/regular-expression-for-the-opposite-result)

Comment: What about `seq_len(as.numeric(strsplit(d, ":")[[1]][2]))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, false assumptions.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, try `d <- "12:18"` with your approach.

Comment: Yeah you probably right there

Comment: That's my bad, I should have gone with a different sequence. Edited for clarity.

Comment: Using `Reduce` smells vaguely of abuse here, although it happens to work (but `Reduce` really means something else). Didn’t you rather mean `do.call`? `do.call(`\``:`\``, as.list(as.numeric(strsplit(d, ':', TRUE))))`

Comment: @KonradRudolph, no. It was abuse, and pretty much works just given this particular set of conditions. `do.call` hadn't occurred to me.